# Azure monitor template value using in subsequent variables

Tags: grafana, azure-monitoring

I'm using the azure monitor datasource which has a query variable subscriptions() which returns all the subscriptions that are available, it appears to return the friendly name and guid of the subscription.

I would like to take part of the friendly name returned to use in subsequent variables but it appears the subscription is only available as the guid.

E.g. my subscription() call returns:

```
"app-prod,0000-guid-0000",
"app-uat,0000-guid-0001",
"app-dev,0000-guid-0002"
```

I would like to take just the "prod", "uat" and "dev" for subsequent calls but can't find a way to do this, is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you are doing? Is `subscriptions()` used for grafana's variable creation, or in some queries themselves? And if latter, how is it used, and how do you envision to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that Grafana is not for data manipulation by default and you need to manipulate that variable result.

You can send that value to suitable datasource in `middle variable`, which will replace that string as you need. You have Azure already, so you may use Azure. For example use KQL - log query:

```
print name = replace_string('${subscription:text}', 'app-', '')
```

[image]

Of course you may use different datasources, which have support for that, e.g. MySQL `SELECT REPLACE('${subscription:text}','app-','')` or you can use another string functions - substring, regexp, ....

It can be also simple print of `${subscription:text}` and then use right `Regex` option in the Grafana variable definition.

Comment: amazing - exactly what I needed, been pondering on and off for months how to fix this!